# I checked single radio buttoon and insert boolean value (like 1) in database

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I have created an online examination system, and I have add question and different option like below screenshot:

[image: Add Questions]

MY Questions: I have add Question (like 1+1= ?) and its different options on Above screenshot, so I have checked right answer and datebase insert value like 1

**View:**

```
<?php echo form_open('admin/Examinations/add_questions/' . $examination_test_id, $attributes); ?>
<div class="box-body">
    <input type="hidden" name="examination_test_id" value="<?php echo $result['examination_test_id']; ?>"/>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Question Name</label>
        <textarea name="question_name" id="question_name" class="form-control" rows="2" placeholder="Enter Question"></textarea><br/>
        <input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Add Options" class="btn btn-primary"/>
    </div>
    <div id="TextBoxContainer" class="form-group">
        <!-- Textboxes will be added here -->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="box-footer">
    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</div>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#btnAdd").bind("click", function () {
            var div = $("<div />");
            div.html(GetDynamicTextBox(""));
            $("#TextBoxContainer").append(div);
        });

        $("body").on("click", ".btn-danger", function () {
            $(this).closest("div").remove();
        });
    });
    function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
        return  '<table class="table table-bordered">' +
                '<tr>' +
                '<td style="width:140%">' + '<input name = "DynamicTextBox[]" type="text" value = "' + value + '" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Options"/>&nbsp;' + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + '<input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="1" class="flat-red"/>' + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + '<input type="button" value="Remove" class="btn btn-danger"/>' + '</td>' +
                '</tr>' +
                '</table>'
    }
</script>
```

**Model:**

```
 public function insert($last_id, $data) {
        var_dump($data);
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($data['DynamicTextBox']); $i++) {
            $insert_data = array(
                'question_id' => $last_id,
                'option_name' => $data['DynamicTextBox'][$i],
                    //'corrrect_answer' => $data['gender'][$i]
            );
            if ($data['gender'] == 1) {
                $insert_data['corrrect_answer'] = $data['gender'][$i];
            } else {
                $insert_data['correct_answer'] = [$i];
            }
            $this->db->insert('examination_option', $insert_data);
        }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
class Examinations extends CI_Controller {

 public function add_questions($examination_test_id) {
        var_dump($_POST);
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('question_name', 'Question Name', 'required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $data = array(
                'page_title' => 'Add Questions',
                'page_name' => 'Examinations/add_questions',
                'admin_username' => $this->session->userdata('username'),
                'result' => $this->examination_test_model->select_id($examination_test_id)
            );
            $data['examination_test_id'] = $examination_test_id;
            $this->load->view('admin/template', $data);
        } else {
            $this->examination_question_model->insert($_POST);
            // redirect('admin/Examinations');
        }
    }
```

}

**var_dump result Below**

```
array (size=5)
  'examination_test_id' => string '1' (length=1)
  'question_name' => string '1+1= ?' (length=6)
  'DynamicTextBox' => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => string '3' (length=1)
      1 => string '2' (length=1)
      2 => string '4' (length=1)
      3 => string '5' (length=1)
      4 => string '6' (length=1)
  'gender' => string '1' (length=1)
  'submit' => string '' (length=0)
```

MY Questions:

I have add Question (like 1+1= ?) and its different options on Above screenshot, so I have checked right answer and dataabse insert value like 1

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @SpamBot My Questions:  I check radio button and database insert value 1 and uncheck radio button insert value 0 in database

Comment: please, add to the question the code for the validation rules in the controller

Comment: @webcrazymaniac I have add Controller

Comment: @webcrazymaniac are you understand my question

Comment: your question is unclear.

Comment: @HananAshraf  MY Questions:    I have add Question (like 1+1= ?) and its different options on Above screenshot,  so  I have checked right answer and datebase insert value like 1

Comment: Please Help me.....

Comment: dude, I see the view, I see the model, I see the var_dump result, but I don't see the controller. Show me the Controller code

Comment: @webcrazymaniac i add controller code

Answer (score 0):

Submitting a form submits form element name and respective values,
as I can see in this case there is a radio button which has a default value of "1"

```
'<td>' + '<input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="1" class="flat-red"/>' + '</td>'
```

you are generating the whole row which includes  text box and radio button, but the value of radio button is same in all rows.

there need to have different values for your different radio button so that you can save all answers and also the answer which is set as "correct answer".